# How often can a Windows 8 Live Tile be updated?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, live-tile

I'm new to Windows 8 and I'm particularly interested in Live Tiles.

I was wondering - How frequently can an app update a live tile? For example, is it possible to create a clock with seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Live Tile update every second is far too frequent.

The [MSDN guidelines for Live Tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx) documentation does not set explicit limits on how often a tile can be updated, but does make a few recommendations about the frequency of updates.  For an app with very frequently changing content, the highest average frequency expected is approximately 15 minutes.  A few choice excerpts:

> For nonpersonalized content, such as weather updates, we recommend that the tile be updated no more than once every 30 minutes. This allows your tile to feel up-to-date without overwhelming your user.
>
> For example, a busy social media app might update every 15 minutes, a weather app every two hours, a news app a few times a day, a daily offers app once a day, and a magazine app monthly.

Recommendations for clock updates are absent, as that isn't an intended purpose for Live Tile updates.  The apps in the store showing the time on their tile use scheduled tile notifications creatively (intended to be used for one-time calendar events), or frequently push notifications to WNS (Windows Push Notifications Service).  The former is very tough, if not impossible, to implement correctly even for per-minute precision (see app reviews), and the latter is prone to being flagged as abuse and throttled by WNS.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/11/02/updating-live-tiles-without-draining-your-battery.aspx) explains the thinking behind live tiles and how they are implemented, which I'm sure you'll find useful.
I haven't seen a limit on frequency of sending a notification, but practically seconds might be unrealistic to assume consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to display live clock with seconds running in the tile. But It is getting updated every 4 seconds. So, minimum amount of time needed to update tile is 4 seconds. We cannot reduce more than that.