# Windows 8 store app: how to have the app live tile change constantly of colour (and text)?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

Is there a way to have a live tile app on the start menu being 'constantly' (as many times as possible per minute for example) change the whole colour of the tile following a precise cycle (this is a feature we want not just a design thing)

Judging by this answer to a close question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15086232/867899

> It's not possible if your app is not running, even with the background task refresh frequency is 15 minutes.
>   For now this scenario is simply not supported.

I wonder if it's actually doable and in the case that your app is actually running the app is not full screen (of course) or snapped and the start menu is open, how long will it be possible to have that tile constantly updated then?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed by [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497542/how-often-can-a-windows-8-live-tile-be-updated).  If your app is running, frequent tile updates, while doable, are frowned upon by MS as this isn't the intended purpose of the Live Tiles.

From the [MS Guidelines and checklist for tiles and badges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx):

> Inappropriate Use of tile notifications
>
> Don't use live tiles if you don't have interesting, new, personalized content for the user.

This being the case, it's quite likely that the feature you described would get your app rejected from the Store.

Comment: Sandra, one more thing, then if i accept the fact to use a 10 minutes or so update rate, is it even possible to change the background color of the tile 'by logic' or would it be mandatory to use tricks like generating an image actually? Thanks again

Comment: @freeeman It looks like you'd have to generate the image. You can only set the tile background color from your app manifest -- which would mean you can only change it per deployment/update.

Comment: The tile's background color is going to be taken from your app manifest.  If you need to change it on the fly, unfortunately you'll have to use an image.